# Calculate inductance and capacitance of a double layer antenna (RFID)

Tags: antenna, inductance, rfid, pcb-antenna, nfc

I want to design an antenna that will work with RFID NFC chip [NHS3152](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NHS3152.pdf).

The NHS3152 IC specs are:
[image: IC Capacitance at precise measurement conditions]

<sub>IC capacitance at precise measurement conditions</sub>

For this particular IC, there is a [demoboard](https://www.nxp.com/products/rfid-nfc/nfc-hf/ntag-smartsensor/nhs3152-general-starter-kit:NHS3152TEMOADK).

Since I have the schematic (Gerber: [download_link](https://github.com/Pr-ROXFET/Stack_docs/blob/main/NHS3152%20Demo%20PCB.zip?raw=true) It can be opened with [This online tool](https://gerber.ucamco.com/timeout.html) ) files of the antenna I want to:

- Calculate the L and C of the demoboard antenna
- Design my own antenna (which if it has similar specs should work)

From the schematic however, you can see that the antenna is double:

- BOTTOM antenna loop on the bottom layer (here in red)
- TOP antenna loop on the top layer (here in blue)

[image: nhs3152 schematic]

The TOP and BOTTOM antenna loops are separated by the PCB, however they are connected to the same pads.

[image]

- How do I calculate the L and C?
- Is there an easier way to find an antenna that will work with the NHS3152 chip? (For example: all antennas from a certain standard or something.)

**EDIT in response to @Andy aka comment:**

Here is the ZIP of the gerber file in question: https://github.com/Pr-ROXFET/Stack_docs/blob/main/NHS3152%20Demo%20PCB.zip?raw=true, that can be opened this [this online gerber viewer](https://gerber.ucamco.com/timeout.html)
This Gerber design antenna must work for sure, as it is the design of NHS3152Demoboard, a product of NXP that I am currently using (and is working)

[image]

**EDIT: instruction to open Gerber file :**

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]

EDIT: Screenshot Bottom and top:
[image]

Comment: That mag-loop doesn't look to me like it would work given the connections (red and blue) shown.

Comment: @Andy aka I have edited the question with a downloadable Gerber file link: 
the antenna design must work, as it is of a DEMO board of NXP, which i am currently using

Comment: That gerber file doesn't properly open using on-line gerber tools.

Comment: try this one: https://gerber.ucamco.com/timeout.html it works for me!

Comment: I strongly suggest that you do what you have instructed me to do and notice the obvious differences between what you have posted and what you have just offered as gerber files.

Comment: I just checked and it workded 1. Donwloaded from link 2. went to https://gerber.ucamco.com/timeout.html 3. click start a new session 4. dragged and dropped the ZIPPED file (don't unzinp)

Comment: Then you post a screen shot.

Comment: I've just posted the screenshots of how i opened the gerber online, and what i see, hopefully it works

Comment: Post a screen shot of bottom and top copper displayed together. This isn't rocket science. I mean you recommended that gerber viewer and it's fairly easy to use.

Comment: Do you need me to post screenshots cause you are still not able to open the gerber? The layers with teh antenna are .BOT and .SST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The layers with teh antenna are .BOT and .SST*

SST stands for **"silk screen top"** and it is **not** a copper layer. These are the copper layers: -

[image]

This is the SST layer: -

[image]

And **IT ISN'T COPPER.**

Comment: Thanks, so the SST layer ins't copper traces, this makes a lot of sense (very new to PCB design here as you can tell) , thank you.

Comment: is there a reason why the SST layer doesn't trace precisely the antenna, but rather does that crossover? convention or just designer's discretion?

Comment: The SST layer is a visible information layer and may or may not bear some or little resemblance to reality @leoelectrics